# Javascript to manipulate object structure

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object with the following schema:

```
[{
    face:"n",
    values:[
        {time:"15:00",value:5}
        {time:"15:02",value:6}
    ]
},{
    face:"e",
    values:[
        {time:"15:01",value:7}
        {time:"15:02",value:8}
    ]
},{
    face:"s",
    values:[
        {time:"15:01",value:7}
        {time:"15:02",value:8}
    ]
},{
    face:"w",
    values:[
        {time:"15:01",value:7}
        {time:"15:02",value:8}
    ]
}]
```

How to convert it to the following structure:

```
[
    {time:"15:00","n":5,"e":null,"s":null,"w":null},
    {time:"15:01","n":null,"e":7,"s":7,"w":7},
    {time:"15:02","n":6,"e":8,"s":8,"w":8},
]
```

- The number of faces will be fixed (north, east, south, west)
- It is possible that some timestamps are missing. In that case we need to fill the value with 'null' (see example above).

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: Show your current implementation and what you’ve tried.

Comment: You're missing `"n": null` in 15:01 and 15:02 in your expected output.

Comment: I am familiar with javascript array functions. Including map, filter and reduce. But this transformation is not trivial. I was thinking maybe there is a more elegant way than just brute force it

Comment: @RickardElimää Thanks, I fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

**with this approach the ordering is not particular, If you want the exact time ordering then you can sort it using the following custorm sort comparator function**

```
result.sort((a, b) => +a.time.match(/\d+/g).join("") - b.time.match(/\d+/g).join(""))
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    face: "n",
    values: [
      { time: "15:00", value: 5 },
      { time: "15:02", value: 6 },
    ],
  },
  {
    face: "e",
    values: [
      { time: "15:01", value: 7 },
      { time: "15:02", value: 8 },
    ],
  },
  {
    face: "s",
    values: [
      { time: "15:01", value: 7 },
      { time: "15:02", value: 8 },
    ],
  },
  {
    face: "w",
    values: [
      { time: "15:01", value: 7 },
      { time: "15:02", value: 8 },
    ],
  },
];

const map = new Map();
const result = [
  ...arr.reduce((acc, { face, values }) => {
      values.forEach(({ time, value }) => {
        if (!acc.has(time))
          acc.set(time, { time, n: null, e: null, s: null, w: null });
        acc.get(time)[face] = value;
      });
      return acc;
    }, map)
    .values(),
];

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't added what you tried so far (which is kinda useless for this task, IMHO), I will just answer in form of how I would tackle this task.

1. Locate your unique value in your expected output: `time`.
2. Loop through your array, and create an object with keys based on `time`. Save the properties `name` and each of the four faces, by first creating null values for all faces, and then filling it out with one value at time as a new timestamp appears in the array.

   Here is how the whole object will look like:
   `{`
     `"15:00": {time:"15:00","n":5,"e":null,"s":null,"w":null},`
     `"15:01": {time:"15:01","n":null,"e":7,"s":7,"w":7},`
     `"15:02": {time:"15:02","n":6,"e":8,"s":8,"w":8`
   `}`
3. Loop through the object—with `for... in`, [edit] or by simply using `Object.values`—to create an array out of it.

You can probably use some smart Array.reduce() functionality to minimize the code.

Comment: Bah, I just assumed that you couldn't have colons, because I forgot that keys are strings.  Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let old_array = [{
  face: "n",
  values: [
    { time: "15:00", value: 5 },
    { time: "15:02", value: 6 }
  ]
}, {
  face: "e",
  values: [
    { time: "15:01", value: 7 },
    { time: "15:02", value: 8 }
  ]
}, {
  face: "s",
  values: [
    { time: "15:01", value: 7 },
    { time: "15:02", value: 8 }
  ]
}, {
  face: "w",
  values: [
    { time: "15:01", value: 7 },
    { time: "15:02", value: 8 }
  ]
}];

let new_array = []
let times = {}
let faces = {"n": "north", "e": "east", "s": "south", "w": "west"}

old_array.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.values.forEach((val) => {
    if(val.time in times)
      times[val.time][faces[obj.face]] = val.value
    else {
      let newT = {time: val.time, "north": null, "east": null, "south": null, "west": null}
      newT[faces[obj.face]] = val.value
      times[val.time] = newT
      new_array.push(newT)
    }
  })
})

new_array.sort((a,b)=>a.time < b.time ? -1 : (a.time > b.time ? 1 : 0))

console.log(new_array)

// Expected output
// [
//   { time: '15:00', north: 5, east: null, south: null, west: null },
//   { time: '15:01', north: null, east: 7, south: 7, west: 7 },
//   { time: '15:02', north: 6, east: 8, south: 8, west: 8 }
// ]
```